# virtualenv / virtualenvwrapper / django-selectable

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I am trying to use `virtualenv`, and `virtualenvwrapper`, with my Django project. I have installed the `django-selectable` package in a `virtualenv` named `selectable`. My Django project is not in a virtual environment; it is located below my home directory.

I get a message (see below) when I try to run the `virtualenvwrapper` command `setvirtualenvproject`.  However, to me it appears that the file does exist. What am I doing wrong?

**From terminal:**

```
bill@ubuntu:~$ setvirtualenvproject [/home/bill/.virtualenvs/selectable /home/bill/workspace/boatsite]
Setting project for selectable to /home/bill/workspace/boatsite]
bash: [/home/bill/.virtualenvs/selectable/.project: No such file or directory
bill@ubuntu:~$
```

I want to run my project and have it hit `django-selectable` in the `virtualenv` when users enter autocomplete fields in the site's input forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the brackets, run:

```
setvirtualenvproject /home/bill/.virtualenvs/selectable /home/bill/workspace/boatsite
```

Instead of:

```
setvirtualenvproject [/home/bill/.virtualenvs/selectable /home/bill/workspace/boatsite]
```

Comment: Thanks.  Dropping the brackets did it.